# GrailsApplication or Holders in Grails 6

Tags: grails

I'm trying to develop an application using `Grails 6.1.0`, I need to have access to the `application.yml` to retrieve some configs from it, when I'm using `GrailsApplication` like the below example, it always gets me `Cannot get property 'config' on null object`, however when I use `Holders.config.getProperty("environments.dataSource.url")`, I get the property value successfully, is this the right way to access the configs in any part of my Grails application or there is a better way

```
import grails.core.*

class MyService {
GrailsApplication grailsApplication

String greeting() {
    def recipient = grailsApplication.config.getProperty('foo.bar.hello')
    return "Hello ${recipient}"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In grails6, use the grails.util.Holders

```
import grails.util.Holders;

public class Example {
  void someMethod() {
     String appName = Holders.getConfig().getProperty("info.app.name");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm grailsApplication is null or grailsApplication.config is null? may Grails 6 changed the way to retrieve config.

In grails5, I am using follow static method to get config

```
public static String getSeedDataFolder(GrailsApplication application) {
    return application.getConfig().getProperty(SEED_DATA_FOLDER, String.class, DEFAULT_SEED_DATA_FOLDER);
}
```

Comment: According to the error it's `grailsApplication` however in the previous Grails versions this was working fine !!